# Window authentication to MSSQL installed under Linux server

Tags: sql-server, linux, authentication, window

This is my first time trying to setup mssql server under linux server.

**This is my error**

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed.
>   The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with
>   Integrated authentication..

I could login using "sa" and password

Once I use `sqlcmd -E -S linuxsqlserver` or `sqlcmd -S linuxsqlserver` I received the error above.

I followed 2 guide in the link

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5075/configure-sql-server-on-linux-to-use-windows-authentication/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-2017

**My current system**

- Ubuntu 18.04

  - MSSQL
- Window Server 2016

  - AD

**What I have done:**

1. join domain (the domain name is Test1)
2. Creating the Service Principal Name

   - `setspn -a MSSQLSvc/linuxsqlserver.TEST1.COM:1433 sqllinux`
3. Creating the Keytab File for the SQL Server Service

   - `kinit sqllinux@TEST1.COM`
   - `kvno MSSQLSvc/linuxsqlserver.TEST1.COM:1433@TEST1.COM (returned 2)`
   - `sudo ktutil`
   - `addent -password -p MSSQLSvc/linuxsqlserver.Test1.COM:1433@Test1.COM -k 2 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96`
   - `addent -password -p MSSQLSvc/linuxsqlserver.Test1.COM:1433@Test1.COM -k 2 -e rc4-hmac`
   - `wkt /var/opt/mssql/secrets/mssql.keytab`
   - quit
4. Setting up Active Directory Authentication for SQL Server

   - `/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.kerberoskeytabfile /var/opt/mssql/secrets/mssql.keytab`
   - `systemctl restart mssql-server`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at MSSQL error logs, there might be additional information. Default location on Ubuntu: /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog. For instance, I have the same symptom, and I have this in the error logs: SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x80090304, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed.